AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank' when using tensorflow_probability.layers.DenseVariational
I'm trying to use bayesian neural networks, adding a bayesian layer to a neural networks model. Here is the code I'm using and it's from the keras website.
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import tensorflow_probability as tfp



dataset_size = 4898
batch_size = 256
train_size = int(dataset_size * 0.85)

# Create training and evaluation datasets
def get_train_and_test_splits(train_size, batch_size=1):
    # We prefetch with a buffer the same size as the dataset because th dataset
    # is very small and fits into memory.
    dataset = (
        tfds.load(name="wine_quality", as_supervised=True, split="train")
        .map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.cast(y, tf.float32)))
        .prefetch(buffer_size=dataset_size)
        .cache()
    )
    # We shuffle with a buffer the same size as the dataset.
    train_dataset = (
        dataset.take(train_size).shuffle(buffer_size=train_size).batch(batch_size)
    )
    test_dataset = dataset.skip(train_size).batch(batch_size)

    return train_dataset, test_dataset

# get train and test data
train_dataset, test_dataset = get_train_and_test_splits(train_size, batch_size)


# Compile, train, and evaluate the model
hidden_units = [8, 8]
learning_rate = 0.001
num_epochs = 100
mse_loss = keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()


def run_experiment(model, loss, train_dataset, test_dataset):

    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(learning_rate=learning_rate),
        loss=loss,
        metrics=[keras.metrics.RootMeanSquaredError()],
    )

    print("Start training the model...")
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=num_epochs, validation_data=test_dataset)
    print("Model training finished.")
    _, rmse = model.evaluate(train_dataset, verbose=0)
    print(f"Train RMSE: {round(rmse, 3)}")

    print("Evaluating model performance...")
    _, rmse = model.evaluate(test_dataset, verbose=0)
    print(f"Test RMSE: {round(rmse, 3)}")


# Create model inputs
FEATURE_NAMES = [
    "fixed acidity",
    "volatile acidity",
    "citric acid",
    "residual sugar",
    "chlorides",
    "free sulfur dioxide",
    "total sulfur dioxide",
    "density",
    "pH",
    "sulphates",
    "alcohol",
]


def create_model_inputs():
    inputs = {}
    for feature_name in FEATURE_NAMES:
        inputs[feature_name] = layers.Input(
            name=feature_name, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32
        )
    return inputs

# Define the prior weight distribution as Normal of mean=0 and stddev=1.
# Note that, in this example, the we prior distribution is not trainable,
# as we fix its parameters.
def prior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    prior_model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfp.layers.DistributionLambda(
                lambda t: tfp.distributions.MultivariateNormalDiag(
                    loc=tf.zeros(n), scale_diag=tf.ones(n)
                )
            )
        ]
    )
    return prior_model


# Define variational posterior weight distribution as multivariate Gaussian.
# Note that the learnable parameters for this distribution are the means,
# variances, and covariances.
def posterior(kernel_size, bias_size, dtype=None):
    n = kernel_size + bias_size
    posterior_model = keras.Sequential(
        [
            tfp.layers.VariableLayer(
                tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL.params_size(n), dtype=dtype
            ),
            tfp.layers.MultivariateNormalTriL(n),
        ]
    )
    return posterior_model

def create_bnn_model(train_size):
    inputs = create_model_inputs()
    features = keras.layers.concatenate(list(inputs.values()))
    features = layers.BatchNormalization()(features)

    # Create hidden layers with weight uncertainty using the DenseVariational layer.
    for units in hidden_units:
        features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1 / train_size,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )(features)

    # The output is deterministic: a single point estimate.
    outputs = layers.Dense(units=1)(features)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

num_epochs = 500
train_sample_size = int(train_size * 0.3)
small_train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch().take(train_sample_size).batch(batch_size)

bnn_model_small = create_bnn_model(train_sample_size)
run_experiment(bnn_model_small, mse_loss, small_train_dataset, test_dataset)

sample = 10
examples, targets = list(test_dataset.unbatch().shuffle(batch_size * 10).batch(sample))[
    0
]
def compute_predictions(model, iterations=100):
    predicted = []
    for _ in range(iterations):
        predicted.append(model(examples).numpy())
    predicted = np.concatenate(predicted, axis=1)

    prediction_mean = np.mean(predicted, axis=1).tolist()
    prediction_min = np.min(predicted, axis=1).tolist()
    prediction_max = np.max(predicted, axis=1).tolist()
    prediction_range = (np.max(predicted, axis=1) - np.min(predicted, axis=1)).tolist()

    for idx in range(sample):
        print(
            f"Predictions mean: {round(prediction_mean[idx], 2)}, "
            f"min: {round(prediction_min[idx], 2)}, "
            f"max: {round(prediction_max[idx], 2)}, "
            f"range: {round(prediction_range[idx], 2)} - "
            f"Actual: {targets[idx]}"
        )


compute_predictions(bnn_model_small)

num_epochs = 500
bnn_model_full = create_bnn_model(train_size)
run_experiment(bnn_model_full, mse_loss, train_dataset, test_dataset)

compute_predictions(bnn_model_full)

But I get this error:
File "/Users/S/Documents/B/Prediction/test1.py", line 148, in <module>
    bnn_model_small = create_bnn_model(train_sample_size)
  File "/Users/S/Documents/B/Prediction/test1.py", line 131, in create_bnn_model
    features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
  File "/Users/S/.local/share/virtualenvs/B-hz56sUDM/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf_keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/Users/S/.local/share/virtualenvs/B-hz56sUDM/lib/python3.9/site-packages/tf_keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 251, in assert_input_compatibility
    ndim = x.shape.rank
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'

I tried using from tf_agents.environments import tf_py_environment environment = tf_py_environment.TFPyEnvironment(environment) As recommended here. The problem was that it needed numpy<1.20 which resulted in many conflicts with other libraries.

I also tried a sequential keras model like here: link
But I get this error:
ValueError: Only instances of keras.Layer can be added to a Sequential model. Received: <tensorflow_probability.python.layers.dense_variational_v2.DenseVariational object at 0x100ab0a60> (of type <class 'tensorflow_probability.python.layers.dense_variational_v2.DenseVariational'>)
